# Wireshark throughput comparison

Tags: wireshark, tcp, throughput, lte

I performed a download throughput test with a mobile handset under LTE network, catching the following logs:

1. L1/L2/L3 log with proprietary vendor device's logging tool
2. Wireshark log with tPacketCapture app installed on the handset

The test has been performed downloading 6 files in parallel by using HTTP protocol, so 6 TCP threads have been opened by the device. Throughput has been calculated in three ways:

1. **L1 scheduled throughput**: by logging tool, considering the downloaded bits (from Transport Block Size in LTE PDSCH) only when the handset is scheduled by the network --> about **140 Mbps** on average (out of 5 test attempts)
2. **L1 real throughput**: by logging tool, summing the total downloaded bits (from Transport Block Size in LTE PDSCH) and dividing by the total time --> about **60 Mbps** on average (out of 5 test attempts)
3. **Wireshark throughput** --> opening caught *pcap file on Wireshark and getting the throughput value filtering by source IP address (server) & destination IP address (mobile handset) and going to "Statistics --> Capture file properties" --> about **90 Mbps** on average (out of 5 test attempts)

The result of throughput 1. is in line with the one directly given by the logging tool, so it is 100% correct. The throughput 2. is calculated from the same data of throughput 1, so it is 100% correct. The throughput 3. is calculated by wireshark and my main doubts are here.

I expected a similar throughput value for 2. and 3. ways, since also Wireshark sums the total bits and divide them by the time, or at least L1 real throughput slightly higher than Wireshark throughput, which is calculated at a higher layer (IP layer, plus 14 byte of "Ethernet header" added by wireshark for each packet).

Why wireshark throughput is higher than the L1 real one? Is there any overhead or any data counted twice, taken into account by wireshark that I didn't filter out?

Answer (score 0):

> Wireshark throughput --> opening caught *pcap file on Wireshark and
>   getting the throughput value filtering by source IP address (server) &
>   destination IP address (mobile handset) and going to "Statistics -->
>   Capture file properties" --> about 90 Mbps on average (out of 5 test
>   attempts)

Wireshark's display filter doesn't change pcap file properties, thus you better use other WS statistics where you have "limit to display filter" option

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please suggest some SW statistics  name?

Comment: You can try `Statistics->Conversations` there you's see both bytes and durations for each "stream", if you have many of them you can export them into excel to calculate there

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. I read "SW" instead of "WS" statistics. Good suggestion, i will try!